# Don't get why I'm getting an 'int' object is not iterable Error

Tags: python

Don't get why I'm getting an TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
first_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
second_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
total = sum(first_age, second_age)
print("Together you're {} years old".format(total))
```

```
Enter your age: 1
Enter your age: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6375ca82c6eb> in <module>
      4 second_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
      5 
----> 6 total = sum(first_age, second_age)
      7 
      8 print("Together you're {} years old".format(total))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6375ca82c6eb> in <module>
      4 second_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
      5 
----> 6 total = sum(first_age, second_age)
      7 
      8 print("Together you're {} years old".format(total))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum` can only be used with iteratable objects. See the official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

The syntax itself is

```
sum(iterable[, start])
```

If you only need to sum two integers use `+` operator like in the below code.

```
sum = first_age + second_age
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `sum()` is for totaling iteratables. So if you input `sum([7,8])` you will return `15`. That is why you are getting the error, because it is trying to iterate over an integer type rather than an array.

A fix would be as follows:

```
first_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
second_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
total = sum([first_age,second_age])
print(f"Together you're {total} years old.")
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? This is the correct answer.

Comment: Are you sure you want use list here ?

Comment: @CodeIt Here it does make more sense to just use plain addition but I believe that the op was looking for directions on how to use the sum function.

Comment: @JDPellock That is correct. The question is not "how do I add integers?" The question is specifically about an error occurring when `sum()` is used with two integers passed to it.

Comment: @JDPellock You have clearly mentioned in your answer that `sum([7,8])` would return the sum of 7 and 8. Then why are not using the same in the code. Can't you just use `sum([first_age,second_age])` ?

Comment: @CodeIt Appending the items to an empty list accomplishes the same thing as `[first_age,second_age]`, just uses a minor difference in resources

Comment: @JDPellock For better understanding i believe `sum([first_age,second_age]` is better as you have already mentioned how it works in your answer.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Python doesn't have arrays. In this answer it is written *The function sum() is for totaling arrays.*

Comment: @CodeIt That is true. JD did use the wrong terminology. I've applied an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

According to the docs:

```
 sum(iterable[, start])
```

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

You want to just use addition.

```
first_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
second_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
total = first_age + second_age
print("Together you're {} years old".format(total))
```

Comment: While this is absolutely true, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Added edit explaining where the `sum()` function should be used.